# Puppet: Trying to configure puppet client for first use but got some problems with certificates

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I'm trying to configure my clinet 'Itai-test' to receive puppet settings from the puppet server which is called 'puppetmaster'.

On the server I ran:

```
[root@puppetmaster requests]# puppet cert --generate itai-test.domain
Error: A Certificate already exists for itai-test.domain
[root@puppetmaster requests]# puppet cert --sign itai-test.domain
Error: Could not find certificate request for itai-test.domain
[root@puppetmaster requests]#
```

On the puppet client I ran:

```
[root@itai-test temp]# puppet agent --server puppetmaster.domain --waitforcert 60 --test
Notice: Did not receive certificate
Notice: Did not receive certificate
Notice: Did not receive certificate
```

More information:
On server:

```
[root@puppetmaster ~]# puppet cert --revoke Itai-test
Error: Could not find a serial number for itai-test
[root@puppetmaster ~]# puppet cert --revoke itai-test
Error: Could not find a serial number for itai-test
[root@puppetmaster ~]# puppet cert --clean itai-test
Error: Could not find a serial number for itai-test
[root@puppetmaster ~]# puppet cert --list
[root@puppetmaster ~]# puppet cert --sign itai-test
Error: Could not find certificate request for itai-test
[root@puppetmaster ~]#
```

On client:

```
[root@itai-test ~]# rm -rf /usr/lib/puppet/ssl
[root@itai-test ~]# puppet agent --server puppetmaster.domain --waitforcert 60
[root@itai-test ~]# ping puppetmaster.domain
PING puppetmaster (192.168.X.X) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from puppetmaster (192.168.X.X): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.294 ms
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does you client know how to find the server?

```
root@client# ping puppet
```

What certname will the client use when connecting to the server?

```
root@client# puppet config print certname
```

Remove the ssl details on the client

```
root@client# rm -rf /var/lib/puppet/ssl
```

Remove all traces of the client on the server

```
root@puppet# puppet node clean $client_certname
root@puppet# puppet node deactivate $client_certname
```

Comment: Thanks for "puppet config print certname" -- very useful and I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow the certname was not matching with my hostname, I fixed it by setting [certname in puppet.conf](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/config_about_settings.html)

Comment: Docs have moved. See [certname in puppet.conf](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/configuration.html#certname) instead.

Answer (score 3):

First: On Server

```
puppet cert --revoke Itai-test
puppet cert --clean Itai-test
```

Second: On Client

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/puppet/ssl
puppet agent --server [puppetmaster domain name] --waitforcert 60
```

Third: On Server

```
puppet cert --list (you should see your host)
puppet cert --sign Itai-test
```

Also, double check that your client can reach your [puppetmaster domain name].

Comment: I've edited my question with the results of the commands you mentioned, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got out of sync somehow.  Assuming this is really just a test instance... On the server, run `puppet node clean itai-test.domain`. Then, on the client run `rm -rf /var/lib/puppet/ssl`.  Now your SSL cert for the client is gone.  Run `puppet agent --server puppetmaster.domain --waitforcert 60 --test` on the client and look for the certificate request on the server.

Comment: I had the same problem as the op, and this finally worked for me.